# Error "Mixed Content" al solicitar imagen desde petición http en angular

Tags: angular, imagen, http, https, jspdf

Tengo una aplicación de angular y quiero agregar una imagen a un pdf, mediante la librería **jsPDF** la cual se solicita desde un servicio que es una url bajo protocolo **http**

> http://xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx

El problema es de que la pagina donde hace el proceso del pdf esta bajo protocolo **https** y me genera el siguiente error

> Mixed Content: The page at **"*pagina - https*"** was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element ***"servicio de la imagen - http"*** This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

Automáticamente se cambia la url del servicio a **https** por lo cual no funciona ya que el servicio externo solo funciona con http y no es posible cambiarlo a **https**

He probado con **DomSanitizer** de angular para poder hacer el contenido seguro pero no funciona

De manera local funciona correctamente no hay ningún problema al solicitar la imagen todo ocurre en un ambiente seguro (https)

Answer (score 0):

Debido a las políticas no te lo permitirá hacer directamente en el navegador con JavaScript o cualquier equivalente, mi recomendación es usando PHP obtengas la imagen proveniente del servicio y luego la retornes a tu frontend, es decir en vez de consumir directamente el servicio con JavaScript hazlo con Php o Nodejs, Luego simplemente haz la petición a tu propio servidor y retorna la imagen.

Ten en cuenta que igualmente necesitarás tener HTTPS en el servidor donde tengas el PHP o NODEJS, puedes hacer la petición usando CURL en PHP.

Espero haberte ayudado, Saludos.

Comment: Muy bien entiendo lo de consumir el servicio desde el server, entonces yo mandaría una cadena de base64 o como seria ese proceso para enviar la imagen al cliente?

Comment: Puedes retornar una cadena base64 o guardar la imagen para no hacer más peticiones al servicio (si la imagen no cambia) y retornar la ruta de la imagen en el servidor, te recomendaría lo primero es más fácil y cómodo para ti.

Comment: voy a intentar la opción de la cadena base64 ya que haga pruebas te comento, el servidor también se aloja con https crees que haya algún problema parecido si por ser http?

Comment: No, Curl tiene opción para omitir SSL como por ejemplo: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`